# Sharing index mapping configuration in NEST 2.3.3?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

Upgrading Elastic & NEST search from 1.6.2 to 2.3.3.

We used be able to share the same `PutMappingDescriptor` between `ElasticClient.CreateIndex()` and `ElasticClient.Map()`.

But in 2.3.3, the `CreateIndex` needs `TypeMappingDescriptor` and `Map` requires `PutMappingDescriptor`.

How do we share the same mapping configuration?

Comment: I am also interested in the same question.

Answer (score 1):

The official Nest developers answered this question in their github, [linked here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/2196).

Basically, you don't use `Func<PutMappingDescriptor<Project>, IPutMappingRequest>` but `PutMappingDescriptor<Project>` directly. by newing up a `PutMappingDescriptor<Project>` and build up your fluent mapping from there.

Creating index expects `ITypeMapping` while updating index expects `IPutMappingRequest` which implements `ITypeMapping`. So you can satisfy both by using `PutMappingDescriptor`.

To create an index, use:

```
client.CreateIndex("projects", c => c
    .Mappings(ms => ms
        .Map(m => GetMapping())
    )
);

```
where you ignore `m` passed in in the lambda and use the one you created. The reason why you can do that can be found in NEST's [source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/9cab2174dd988fb8cf6b440fdd24d32517eab5b0/src/Nest/Mapping/Mappings.cs) where it creates an empty TypeMappingDescriptor for your to further build upon:

`public MappingsDescriptor Map<T>(Func<TypeMappingDescriptor<T>, ITypeMapping> selector) where T : class =>
            Assign(typeof (T), selector?.Invoke(new TypeMappingDescriptor<T>()));`

To update mapping, do:

`client.Map(GetMapping());`